# How to calculate speed of recyclerView inside NestedScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have recyclerView inside NestedScrollView. I want to calculate speed to recyclerview but it is not working inside nestedScrollView.

This is code to calculate scroll speed which is working without NestedScrollView. I want to make it work with NestedScrollView also.

I have set nested scrolling false but its not working

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Class:

```
abstract class ScrollSpeedRecycleViewScrollListener(private val maxScrollSpeedForAdInjection: Int) :
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

  
    var currentScrollSpeed: Int = 0

    private var previousFirstVisibleItem = 0
    private var previousEventTime: Long = 0

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager

        if (layoutManager is LinearLayoutManager) {
            val firstItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            if (previousFirstVisibleItem != firstItemPosition) {
              
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

        when (newState) {
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if (currentScrollSpeed > maxScrollSpeedForAdInjection) {
                    listNeedsRefresh()
                }
                currentScrollSpeed = 0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The concept of speed involves distance covered over a certain period of time. You can get the values scrolled (distance) using the dx or dy in the onScrolled method. To get time you would need to get some timestamps at the point where you're getting the distance values and then use a calculation of `speed = distance / time`. But your also going to need calculate the difference between calls of onScrolled. so it'll actually end up as

`speed = (distance2 - distance1) / (time2 - time1)`

The problem you're going to have here is that the method will be getting called loads when the user is scrolling fast, and the calculation will need to be done each time and that will have a detrimental effect on the smoothness of the scroll.

I'm willing to bet there is a better way to overcome your problem.